# Integrate C Library with Linux Bridge (brctl) to edit packets

Tags: networking, bridge

I need to deploy a bridging device between a machine and a common network in order to perform some actions to specific packets (protocol-related). The scenario is described in the following image:

[image: Scenario]

My scenario is very latency-sensitive (we need a max RTT of 6ms within a LAN) and I set up a Linux bridge using brctl which performs pretty well (RTT between 2.2ms - 3.5ms). I now need to integrate a library i developed in C with the bridging.  This will change some packets. Is it possible to integrate a C library with brctl?

Note: I'm using a RaspberryPi with RaspianOS as bridging device

Comment: `brctl` is, as the name says, just a controlling program for the bridge. The bridging functionality is implemented by the kernel.

Comment: *Many* years ago in university we did something that sounds a little like this.  To do it we had to write it in C as a kernel module.  It could then be loaded using `modprobe`.  There maybe / should be hooks which will notify your code of the packet before sending it.  I'm afraid I remember practically nothing of the exercise beyond that, but thought I'd mention it to give you something more to google.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Given that, how can i tackle the situation? I wrote a C program and managed the bridging myself on user-space, using libpcap and raw sockets, however it wasn't very efficient...

Comment: Thanks @PhilipCouling! I'll search on that.

Comment: You can use two bridges and two tap devices. Your (userspace) program would be on the process side of each tap devices to do its alterations. Depending on exactly *what* you want to do it's possible linux' built-in firewall features (ebtables or nftables) could already handle it

Comment: @A.B Yes, meanwhile i already found a way to achieve my goals. I managed to use brctl along side with iptables and nfqueue to send filtered packets to an user space application. There i could use my lib, edit the packets and reinject them on the wire. I will post a more detailed solution soon. Thank you!